# iMacros: How to make Value loop just Line 1 file.CSV?

Tags: imacros

iMacros: How to make Value loop just Line 1 file.CSV?

```
SET !DATASOURCE Data_SMS.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=http://google_single
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:frmBlast ATTR=ID:nophn CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:frmBlast ATTR=ID:isiSMS CONTENT={{!COL2}}
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT=
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:frmBlast ATTR=ID:btnSMS
```

Comment: + (-1) from me...: "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved." => I already provided Explanation but got censured by Moderation, Comment got deleted...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep looping on the same Row in your DataSource, then don't use `!LOOP` for `!DATASOURCE_LINE`, (like you are currently doing with `SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}`), but simply hard-code the Row that you want to use...:

```
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET !DATASOURCE Data_SMS.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !LOOP 1
```